# JVM waits for some timeout every time when I load a Smart Contract using Web3j In Java

Tags: web3j

Initially I had a problem with the Web3j object, but after explicitly calling its shutdown method everything works fine (JVM quits immediately, so my application closes). The problem occurs when I call load(...) method of any Smart Contract. For some reason, if I quit the application, JVM hangs for 40-50 seconds until it quits. This is the thread dump: [image: The thread dump]

Here is the code used to load the contract:

[image]

Comment: Hey, could you share some code to try to reproduce the issue. I never experienced anything like that.

Comment: I added some code that loads a contract

Comment: Oh man, this is something very interesting. Apparently it is related to OkHttp, and some cleaning task that starts from the ConnectionPool. It might be related with this: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/4029

Comment: Interesting one. So I deduce your are using java9. Ethereum client doesn't support HTTP/2 so I might suggest you (if possible) to rollback to Java8 as suggested. Or alternatively, you can try connecting via WebSocket to the client.

Comment: Nope. I use Java 8 with Http/1.1. So far after my small research I am 99% sure that the ForkJoinPool is responsible for that (it is executed while I call load()). Also, the cleaning threads from Okhttp are Daemons so they should not block the JVM from closing.